# Apache Client Limitation

Tags: apache, post, get, server

I'm having issues with clients communicating with my Apache server.  Here is my setup:

Arbitrary number of embedded clients on WIFI pushing a 1MB file to my Apache server and then downloading a 1MB file from the server.  This is repeated per client 40 times and then the results of that that unit's upload/download times are posted to the server.  This is a stress test for the embedded devices.

It would seem that I cannot run (within a reasonable time) more than 8 devices simultaneously on a single Apache server in my case which is peculiar.  I tried splitting half of my devices (16 in this case) between two servers on the same router and they worked and could connect with the server, where 16 would definitely have not worked on a single server.  My hopes were to single out either the embedded device, the router, or the server as the issue and I'm now leaning towards the server.

Is there some configuration within Apache that might prevent responses to many GETs?  My embedded devices are both GETing (download) and POSTing (uploading) so either event might need tweaking.  I have little experience with Apache so some help is appreciated.